# MySQL: wrong sorting order in a query with ORDER BY + GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT() + COUNT(*) OVER() window function

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, window-functions, group-concat, mysql-8.0

Apparently, sorting is somehow applied incorrectly in mysql 8 (checked on 8.0.33 to 8.0.35) when query has ORDER BY + GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT() + COUNT(*) OVER() window function. See test case below (**NOTE that it's synthetic and oversimplified for clarity - obviously in a real case grouping wouldn't be run on a single table**).

**Question 1**: why in the first query ordering is not applied as I expect it (i.e. ascending by `sort` field)?

**Question 2**: what would be a recommended fix (or work around)? Duplicating the ordering specification into COUNT(*) OVER() doesn't seem a very elegant or robust solution.

### Schema and test data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    sort INT
);

INSERT INTO users (username, email, sort) VALUES ('user1', 'user1@example.com', 50);
INSERT INTO users (username, email, sort) VALUES ('user2', 'user2@example.com', 30);
INSERT INTO users (username, email, sort) VALUES ('user3', 'user3@example.com', 20);
INSERT INTO users (username, email, sort) VALUES ('user4', 'user4@example.com', 90);
INSERT INTO users (username, email, sort) VALUES ('user5', 'user5@example.com', 40);
INSERT INTO users (username, email, sort) VALUES ('user6', 'user6@example.com', 70);
```

### Unexpected result

Query:

```
SELECT
    sort,
    username,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email) AS email_concat,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_count
FROM users
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sort;
```

(Note: `total_count` is supposed to give a total number of results in a result set, for when query in paginated (pagination omitted from the example)

Result (unexpected, not ordered by `sort`):

```
| sort | username | email_concat      | total_count |
| ---- | -------- | ----------------- | ----------- |
| 50   | user1    | user1@example.com | 6           |
| 30   | user2    | user2@example.com | 6           |
| 20   | user3    | user3@example.com | 6           |
| 90   | user4    | user4@example.com | 6           |
| 40   | user5    | user5@example.com | 6           |
| 70   | user6    | user6@example.com | 6           |
```

Execution plan:

```
 -> Window aggregate with buffering: count(0) OVER () 
    -> Table scan on <temporary>  (cost=2.5..2.5 rows=0)
        -> Temporary table  (cost=0..0 rows=0)
            -> Group aggregate: group_concat(users.email separator ',')
                -> Sort: users.id
                    -> Stream results  (cost=0.85 rows=6)
                        -> Sort: users.sort  (cost=0.85 rows=6)
                            -> Table scan on users  (cost=0.85 rows=6)
```

[DB Fiddle 1 (wrong result)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3p23pACXZVMUHrz7fbgNse/1)

### Expected result

However, if we add ORDER BY into window function (which, in my understanding, is a no-op/redundant in this case), sorting is applied as expected:

```
SELECT
    sort,
    username,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email) AS email_concat,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS total_count
FROM users
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sort;
```

Result (as wanted, ordered by `sort`):

```
| sort | username | email_concat      | total_count |
| ---- | -------- | ----------------- | ----------- |
| 20   | user3    | user3@example.com | 6           |
| 30   | user2    | user2@example.com | 6           |
| 40   | user5    | user5@example.com | 6           |
| 50   | user1    | user1@example.com | 6           |
| 70   | user6    | user6@example.com | 6           |
| 90   | user4    | user4@example.com | 6           |
```

Execution plan:

```
 -> Sort: users.sort
    -> Table scan on <temporary>  (cost=2.5..2.5 rows=0)
        -> Temporary table  (cost=0..0 rows=0)
            -> Window aggregate with buffering: count(0) OVER (ORDER BY NULL ) 
                -> Sort: NULL
                    -> Stream results
                        -> Group aggregate: group_concat(users.email separator ',')
                            -> Sort: users.id
                                -> Stream results  (cost=0.85 rows=6)
                                    -> Table scan on users  (cost=0.85 rows=6)
```

[DB Fiddle 2 (correct result)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3p23pACXZVMUHrz7fbgNse/3)

Comment: What's the point of using an aggregation function like `GROUP_CONCAT()` when you're grouping by the primary key? Nothing is being grouped.

Comment: seems like a bug.  note that the ORDER BY in the over clause is *not* a no-op, its presence causes the default frame to change from `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` to `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, as you can clearly see in your total_count values.  this is described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html  so if you add ORDER BY just to avoid this bug, also specify the frame you want.

Comment: an empty ov works like ORBY BY NULL which gives the windows function no order to count, so it works like a COUNT(*)

Comment: Getting rid of the useless `GROUP_CONCAT()` causes the ordering to be correct. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3p23pACXZVMUHrz7fbgNse/2

Comment: @Barmar they clearly say this is a contrived simplified case demonstrating the problem.  don't get hung up on that.

Comment: @ysth Thanks, missed that part of the question. I've removed the part of my answer that addresses it.

Comment: @nbk yes, a frame (default or not) that starts or ends with CURRENT ROW includes all order-by peers of the current row.

Comment: @ysth thanks for the excellent insight regarding the window function frame!
Just to clarify - in the real-life case the query is paginated - and COUNT(*) OVER () is used to count all rows in the result set (not just the current page).

Comment: @nbk thanks, indeed ORDER BY NULL is a correct workaround, updated my second example

Answer (score 1):

a Window funcrtion needs an order to give the data and it self the right display order.

so add an `ODER BY NULL` for exanple and the order is correct

```
SELECT
    sort,
    username,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email) AS email_concat,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS total_count
FROM users
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sort;
```

But if you need the count of 1,2,3,4,5,6 the you need tpo add a column to siort by

```
SELECT
    sort,
    username,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email) AS email_concat,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS total_count
FROM users
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sort;
```

| sort | username | email_concat | total_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | user3 | user3@example.com | 6 |
| 30 | user2 | user2@example.com | 6 |
| 40 | user5 | user5@example.com | 6 |
| 50 | user1 | user1@example.com | 6 |
| 70 | user6 | user6@example.com | 6 |
| 90 | user4 | user4@example.com | 6 |

```
SELECT
    sort,
    username,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email) AS email_concat,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY sort) AS total_count
FROM users
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sort;
```

| sort | username | email_concat | total_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | user3 | user3@example.com | 1 |
| 30 | user2 | user2@example.com | 2 |
| 40 | user5 | user5@example.com | 3 |
| 50 | user1 | user1@example.com | 4 |
| 70 | user6 | user6@example.com | 5 |
| 90 | user4 | user4@example.com | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/whCfyxWS)

Comment: total_count should always be = 6 in the example (it's a total result count for when pagination is present) - I overlooked the mistake which ```OVER(ORDER BY sort)``` introduced into second example, replaced it now with ```OVER(ORDER BY NULL)``` as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug triggered by the use of `GROUP_CONCAT()`, as removing that produces the correct ordering.

A workaround is to put the grouped query in a subquery, and use `ORDER BY sort` in the main query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
      sort,
      username,
      GROUP_CONCAT(email) AS email_concat,
      COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_count
  FROM users
  GROUP BY id) AS x
ORDER BY sort;
```

And if you want to get a running count instead of a total count, you need to use `OVER (ORDER BY id)`. This also works around the bug somehow.

Comment: This problem is triggered by 4 combined factors mentioned in the question's title (GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT, ORDER BY and window function) - removing any single factor will avoid the problem - but that's not the point, as in my real-life case (not the present contrived example) all 4 are required.

Comment: Wrapping the query into a SELECT and applying ORDER BY to that outer query is a workaround indeed - however it's not always applicable, i.e. if the query is built by some kind of query builder/ORM (as is in my underlying case).

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** I think, you have a combined issue which leeds to an unexpected behavior. Some facts:

1. First of all, when using GROUP BY, the columns in the SELECT clause must either be part of the grouping or be used with an aggregate function. Grouping by id makes no sense, as all id's are different
2. COUNT(*) OVER is a window function which will applied **after** the GROUP BY clause
3. COUNT(*) OVER (), without ORDER BY, calculates a count of **all rows** in the result set without regard to any specific order

**Question 2:** A good a approach for problem like this is, that you first select your data, then use it as a subquery and then order the result as a second step:

```
SELECT sort, username, email_concat, total_count
FROM (
  ... your query ...
) AS q1
ORDER BY sort;
```

Comment: You're right about GROUP BY id making no sense here. However, this is just a minified example to reproduce the problem. The real query has meaningful GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT() and COUNT(*) OVER (to get combined count of rows in presence of pagination) - and has the same problem.